# Facebook Open Graph Article not working properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem where Facebook doesn't display my open graph data correctly. the og:type is set to article so when shared it should show the image, title and description, however all that appears is this:
[image]

Testing it with Open Graph Object Debugger it doesn't show any errors and is able to construct the open graph properties:
[image]

What can be causing the problem to not display the sharing box properly, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used "Fetch new scrape information" twice, then it works. The debugger is a bit buggy sometimes. The data shows up correctly now, in the debugger and when i post it on Facebook. If the problem comes back, you should file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 0):

You must check again in Snippets . maybe you dont have enough of Og type or you make wrong code. here is example but you must change code before using

```
enter code here "<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg/jpg/png">
```

"